# Desktop Duplication Media Foundation Network Transmission

Tags: c

How to encode multiple 2D textures into a video stream for network transmission (Do not create files)

Should I use IMFTransform or IMFSinkWriter and IMFSourceReader

There are no relevant code examples on the internet. May I know who can tell me? Thank you